# OpenGL ES Texture Error 0x500

Tags: java, opengl-es

Error `GLES_CM/GLEScmImp.cpp 0x500` throws which prevents rendering, not providing a detailed log.

What does the 0x500 mean?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was using 16-bit/channel format png. Re-saving the files as 8-bit solved it.